# Mixing c# and vc++

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I've got a code snippet of c# that I've been trying to translate into vc++, but I'm having some difficulties.  So, I'm wondering if it is possible or advisable to mix c# and vc++; that is to say, can I call my c# function from vc++ and vice-versa.  If so, are there tricks to it? If, not, why?

Comment: Why not post the code snippet that you are having trouble with?

Comment: I intend to hack away on it a bit more, and possibly post it as a different question.  This question is as much about my current problem as the idea of mixing the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling C++ code from C# is easy enough and you should be able to find plenty of articles on Pinvoke and other types of interop.

For calling your C# code from C++ - if your C++ app is managed then you should be able to directly reference the C# assembly from your C++ app and use it as normal.

If ypu C++ code is not managed then you will need to use some sort of interop to allow your C++ assembly to call C# code, the only way of doing this that springs to mind is COM.

Try some of these links for more information on COM interop with C#:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/COM_DOTNET_INTEROP.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx?df=100&forumid=14076&exp=0&select=864859

Comment: @Kragen - in your 2nd paragraph did you mean "For calling your C# code from C++..."?  But otherwise great answer!  I've had decent luck using .NET DLLs as ActiveX COM servers in other languages, as described in the second link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix the two, I'd start with C# as the base project and then [register an unmanaged (C++) DLL in your C# project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/usingcppdll.aspx).  That way you can combine the reliability of the managed C# parent application with the speed benefits of C++ in any processor-intensive methods you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Is the VC++ app managed? If so, you could create a C# DLL, use it from your c++ app, and if you so desire, ILMerge them into a single EXE.